Заменяет ли тире запятую перед союзом "а"?

Ему было что сказать, но он смолчал — а что он может против учителя?

Нужна ли запятая перед тире по причине того, что перед "а" она бы стояла, если бы не было тире?

Правильно:
Ему было что сказать, но он смолчал — а что он может против учителя?
Пояснение
Решить задачу можно методом блоков по Лопатину.
  § 132. В сложных синтаксических конструкциях, 
  распадающихся на крупные логико-синтаксические блоки, 
  которые сами по себе являются сложными предложениями или в 
  которых один из блоков оказывается сложным предложением, 
  на стыке блоков ставятся знаки препинания, указывающие на 
  взаимоотношения блоков, при сохранении внутренних знаков, 
  поставленных на своем собственном синтаксическом 
  основании.

Три предикативные основы, связь сочинительная, союзы НО и А.
Граница между блоками проходит по союзу А, там нужно выбрать знак: тире или единый знак (запятая и тире).
Считаем, что отношения пояснительные (комментарий к ситуации) и выбираем тире. В этом случае графика лучше смотрится, да и пауза для тире подходящая.
Решить задачу иначе вряд ли получится: правило сложно подобрать, так как структура предложения нестандартная.
